# Using Linq to compare process name to XML list

Tags: c#, linq, process

I have a list of process names in an XML file and am trying to compare them to the processes currently running on the local machine. I have managed to achieve it in a foreach loop, but I'd ideally like to perform it in Linq as my code is getting crowded with loops. I can;t quite get the syntax right though...

```
XDocument xdoc; // this is populated elsewhere
Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();             

if (allProcesses.Any(_ => xdoc.Descendants("Process").ToList().Contains(_)) {}
```

I think it is because I need to somehow use `allProcesses.ProcessName.Any` as the comparison, but ProcessName wont expose its self without me performing a foreach loop through the processes.

Comment: What is the structure of your xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compare the name of the process.

1. Get a list of process names from the xml (depending on your xml structure: `xdoc.Descendants("Process").Select(x=>x.Value).ToList()`)
2. Compare with the `Process` Name (`process.ProcessName`)

So it could look like this:

```
XDocument xdoc; // this is populated elsewhere

var processList = xdoc.Descendants("Process").Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();             

if (allProcesses.Any(p => processList.Contains(p.ProcessName)) {}
```

Comment: In my XML file some of the Process items are partial names (e.g iexplo for iexplore). How would I reverse the `processList.Contains` to be `ProcessName.Contains` if you see what I mean?

Comment: `if (allProcesses.Any(p => processList.Any(pr => p.Contains(pr))) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var processNames=xdoc.Descendants("Process").Select(e=>e.Value);
var selectedProcess=allProcesses.Where(p=>processNames.Contains(p.ProcessName));
```

First select the process names from your xml, and later filter the process using that collection